# iOS weather report on lock screen

Tags: iphone

The other day I noticed a little weather report the minute I picked up my phone. It looked different from a notification. But I haven’t seen one since. It seems like there’s an app or a hidden feature that might have an option to do this but I don’t know which or how to enable or control it.

Answer (score 2):

Do not Disturb mode + the 'Bedtime' feature show you a Good Morning message once you wake your phone for the first time on a given day. [This Osxdaily article](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/24/see-weather-lock-screen-iphone/) goes in-depth on how to enable it and how it works.

Comment: Great find!!! I think that must be it. However on ios13.3 I don’t see the bedtime feature!! More tips?